# How to implement a sign in with google button using the new Google identity services for web

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am trying for few days to implement into my website a "sign in with google" button using the new Google identity services for web. Google is about to deprecate their old Javascript api.
I did everything as their documents suggest but it just doesn't work.

I need a page that contains the "sign in with google" button and the endpoint page in my website that will have a sign out button and do the sign out when clicked. The most important thing of course is that my website will get the user name, email and photo from google and this is exactly where I am having hard time getting these details back from google's servers. I configured everything right at the google developers console including getting a client id and setting the domain.

Can anyone please help me by writing the necessary code for each page ? Sign in, sign out and get the user's details as long as I am signed in. Thanks a lot in advance !

I tried to implement a sign in button with google and it did not work.

This is the link to their documentation:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Comment: It would be useful if you include some links pointing to the new documentation in your question.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: I meant edit your question